# Disassemble opcode snippets directly in a shell?

Tags: linux, debugging, x86, x86-64, disassembly

I got a small byte-string, with a hex-representation like:

```
6631C08A2500000000
```

Is there a disassembler, which accepts opcodes as a direct input parameter, without the need of a compiled file?

e.g.:

```
$ disassembler -directOpcode 6631C08A2500000000      

0:  66 31 c0                xor    ax,ax
3:  8a 25 00 00 00 00       mov    ah,BYTE PTR ds:0x0
```

Comment: If you can convert it to actual binary (like hex undump), you can feed it to `ndisasm -b 64` or whatever.  Or `objdump` has options for disassembling a flat binary.  You can certainly make a wrapper script that takes a cmd line arg and uses tmp files.  PS: you don't need to and shouldn't run it as root.

Comment: Great Hint! Thx! Formulate it as an answer and I'll accept it! I did it with `ndisasm -b64 <(python -c "print '\x66\x31\xC0\x8A\x25\x00\x00\x00\x00'" )` which is pretty easy scriptable! Thx a lot!

Comment: Feel free to write up a complete answer yourself with a working script to turn `6631C0...` into `'\x66\x31\xC0...'`, or whatever it is that you actually wanted.

Comment: Seems like my question wasn't formulated well enough. I basically just wanted to disassemble a small opcode fragment in the shell by passing it as a string to a program. I wasn't aware of `ndisasm` and couldn't get `objdump` to do it without a file.

Comment: Oh, I didn't realize `objdump  -b binary` wouldn't read from stdin or a named pipe like `<( something )`.  ([Disassembling A Flat Binary File Using objdump](//stackoverflow.com/q/14290879)).  Anyway, still feel free to write up an answer yourself.

Comment: That's exactly what bothered me, thx again! ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because of Peter's helpful comment I found a solution utilizing python2 and some shell pipes:

```
$ python -c "print '6631C08A2500000000'.decode('hex')" | head -c -1 | ndisasm -b32 -

00000000  6631C0            xor ax,ax
00000003  8A2500000000      mov ah,[dword 0x0]
```

I used `head -c -1` to get rid of the trailing newline char, otherwise I get:

```
00000000  6631C0            xor ax,ax
00000003  8A2500000000      mov ah,[dword 0x0]
00000009  0A                db 0x0a
```

Comment: [How to print without newline or space?](//stackoverflow.com/q/493386) might be easier / better than using `head -c -1`

Comment: IDK if `python -c "import sys; sys.stdout.write('6631C08A2500000000'.decode('hex'))"| ndisasm -b32 -` is really much better, then using head?; `print "x",` doesn't work i guess because if the terminal flush.

Comment: More concisely: `echo 4c 8d 2d e7 3d db 03 | xxd -r -p | ndisasm -b64 -`

Answer (score 1):

Try cstool from capstone project.

Install cstool :

```
$ sudo apt install capstone-tool
```

Disassemble your code in AT&T-syntax:

```
$ cstool x64att '6631C08A2500000000'
0  66 31 c0                            xorw  %ax, %ax
3  8a 25 00 00 00 00                   movb  0(%rip), %ah
```

Or intel syntax:

```
$ cstool x64 '6631C08A2500000000'
0  66 31 c0                            xor   ax, ax
3  8a 25 00 00 00 00                   mov   ah, byte ptr [rip]
```